# How to calculate sales commission in java

Tags: java, methods, calc

I would like to know how I perform this calculation of the sales commission, I need to do the method and I'm not getting it. There is the value sold in relation to the goal, at first it would be less than 50% the seller earns only 1% and has the value sold in relation to the goal of 50 to 70% and the seller earns 2.5%. Where is the blank space of the if, is where I don’t know what to put, because I don’t know how to put less than half a value or even one value until the other, which in this case is 50 to 70%, e and from 71 to 100% you get 3.5%.
I believe that the Sales Goal attribute needs to be in the method, because the program has to understand that the value sold was less than half of the goal.

```
public class Salesman {
    //defining attributes
    private String name;
    private double salesGoal;
    private double totalSold;

    public double calculateCommission() {
        double soldValue;
        if (totalSold <  ) {
            soldValue =(totalSold * 1.01);
        }else if(totalSold >= ){
            soldValue =(totalSold * 1.025);
        }else if(totalSold >= ){
            soldValue =(totalSold * 1.035);
        }else{
            soldValue = 0;
        }

        return soldValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to make some diagrams
[image: What goes in what goes out]

What goes in, and what goes out determines your method signature.

```
public double calculateCommission(double soldValue, double goal) { 
  return 0d;
}
```

And then create some kind of flow diagram

[image: Flow diagram]

```
public double calculateCommissionRate(double soldValue, double goal) { 
  double ratio = soldValue / goal;

  if (ratio < 0.5) return 0.01;
  if (ratio < 0.7) return 0.025;
  return 0.035;
}
```

Try to think of your goal or sales target as a cake. What you need to know, is how much of the cake has been sold (`ratio = sold/cake`). That's the first thing to calculate.

And a percentage is actually a ratio as well. ["pro-cent" means x/100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage). so 50% is actually 50/100 , which is actually 0.5.

So, we can just compare those 2 ratios directly with each other.

---

I just realized that you may want to apply your commission-rate as well.
In that case, you have to multiply it with the `soldValue`.

```
public double calculateCommission(double soldValue, double goal) { 
  double commissionRate = calculateCommissionRate(soldValue, goal);
  return soldValue * commissionRate;
}
```

*Final remark (out of scope): `double` is fine to store a ratio, but aren't that good for monetary values (i.e. the inputs of your method), due to all kind of rounding errors. You may want to use `BigDecimal` or alternatively, perhaps `Integer` and multiply your numbers by 100 to also store the decimals. Showing your values to the end user is then just a matter of using a decent formatter.*

Comment: I didn't understand your division, to be clear, what I need is the following, let's imagine running the program:
Enter your goal: 1000
Enter the sale price: 499
Upon seeing this, the seller made less than half of his goal, that is, he will earn 1% over 499, how do I make the program understand that the sale value was less than half?

Comment: seeing your code I imagine it will run as follows:
Ratio = 499/1000, so it results in 0.499, so far so good it will be less than 0.5, just following that the return is 0.01, would have to appear the amount he profited from this sale, not only show 0.01

Comment: @felipi indeed, following up on your remark. So, 0.01 would mean that his commission rate is 1%. And 1% of 499 would mean that he gets 4.99 usd. So, that's what the last part of my answer is about. That's why I finally added a 2nd function, which multiplies the commission rate with the soldValue. (1% * 499usd = 4.99usd).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```java
    private String name;
    private double salesGoal;
    private double totalSold;

    public double calculateCommission() {
        double seventyPercentOfSalesGoal = salesGoal * 0.70;
        double fiftyPercentOfSalesGoal = salesGoal * 0.50;
        
        if (totalSold >= seventyPercentOfSalesGoal) {
            return totalSold * 0.025;
        } else if (totalSold >= fiftyPercentOfSalesGoal) {
            return totalSold * 0.01;
        } 
        return 0;
    }
```

you need to check whether the higher threshold is passed before you check the lower one. I've also removed the variable as you can just return a value the moment you know what you need to calculate.

Comment: In this case it is less than 50%, but what about the question of the sales target? How will the program understand when I enter any sales target, and the sales value is lower than the target?

Comment: You need to add a constructor to initialise the state of the class variables in the example code you’ve given

Comment: What I need to do to get a better understanding is, let's imagine running the program:
Enter the seller's goal: 1000.
Enter the vendor's sold value: 499
How do I make the program understand that the value of selling was less than half of the target and it will earn 1%, so successively with the other values ​​that I reported, from 50 to 70% profit 2.5 ....